# Open an html page to an anchor on Mac OS from command line

Tags: macos, shell, command-line

I would like to open a web page to a to specific anchor.

eg:

> open index.html#intro

When I try this, I can get error saying

> index.htm.l#intro does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't open because it thinks you're typing the file name `index.htm.l#intro`. As far as I can tell you can't open a page from the command line to an anchor.

As a workaround you could include javascript to jump to the specified anchor using the onLoad function or Jquery document.ready.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up generating a temporary file and opening that, with {0}=Source HTML file, {1}=Anchor:

    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=file:///{0}#{1}\" /> 
    </head></html>

Answer (score 2):

You could also use AppleScript command line (in Terminal):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "file://{full_path}/index.html#intro"'
```

in which {full_path} is the absolute path to the file.

Comment: Thanks for this; here's a [wrapper](http://pastebin.com/8F0TZvrf) I just wrote for OSX's `open` that will do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible. The command:

```
open file:///path/to/file.html#test
```

successfully opens the specified HTML file in the system default browser, but doesn't pass the `#test` anchor to that file. Doing the same thing with an `http://` URL works, though. My suspicion is that the Apple Events used to handle a `file://` request only specify a filename, not a URL, so the anchor cannot be preserved.

Comment: Right... I noticed the same. It respects the anchor for http:// bu not file:///. I tried replacing the anchor with %23 (the ASCII equivalent), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided here automatically uses the default browser: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/197284/202702

> A non-specific approach is:
>
> `osascript -e 'open location "file:///Users/me/index.html#my-anchor"'`